# JavaFx ListView<Float> set all items font color

Tags: java, css, listview, nullpointerexception

I have a problem in updating an item in a listview, I' m trying to change the font color in a listview by the number.

[image: my listView]

I mean if the number is < 6.0, the specific item font color should be red, otherwise it should be green.
Here's the code I tried:

```
public void loadMarksListView(String key){
    ObservableList<Float> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    items.addAll(subjectsMarks.get(key));
    marksListView.setItems(items);

    marksListView.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<Float>, ListCell<Float>>() {
        @Override
        public ListCell<Float> call(ListView<Float> param) {
            return new ColoredCell();
        }
    });
}

static class ColoredCell extends ListCell<Float>{
    @Override
    public void updateItem(Float number, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(number, empty);

        if (Float.parseFloat(number.getClass().toString()) < 6.0f){
            this.setTextFill(Color.RED);
        }
        else{
            this.setTextFill(Color.GREEN);
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
Stack trace

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
at main.Controller$ColoredCell.updateItem(Controller.java:88)
at main.Controller$ColoredCell.updateItem(Controller.java:83)
at javafx.scene.control.ListCell.updateItem(ListCell.java:480)
at javafx.scene.control.ListCell.access$300(ListCell.java:72)
at javafx.scene.control.ListCell$4.invalidated(ListCell.java:299)
at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:111)
at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:146)
at javafx.scene.control.ListCell.setListView(ListCell.java:305)
at javafx.scene.control.ListCell.updateListView(ListCell.java:494)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ListViewSkin.createCell(ListViewSkin.java:292)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ListViewSkin.lambda$new$366(ListViewSkin.java:99)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.getCell(VirtualFlow.java:1777)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.getCellLength(VirtualFlow.java:1879)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.computeViewportOffset(VirtualFlow.java:2528)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.layoutChildren(VirtualFlow.java:1189)
at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1087)
at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1093)
at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1093)
at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1093)
at javafx.scene.Scene.doLayoutPass(Scene.java:552)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.pulse(Scene.java:2397)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.lambda$runPulse$30(Toolkit.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.runPulse(Toolkit.java:354)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.firePulse(Toolkit.java:381)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:510)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:490)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.lambda$runToolkit$404(QuantumToolkit.java:319)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$49(GtkApplication.java:139)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Why are you using `Float.parseFloat(number.getClass().toString())`?
The output of `number.getClass().toString()` is `class java.lang.Float` in the form of a string, and using the `Float.parseFloat()` method on it will throw a `NumberFormatException`. Maybe that's the error: you should just write `if(number < 6.0f)`.

Comment: it's an error, but it doesn't work thought, the stack trace says that there is a null pointer exception.

Comment: Can you please post the stack trace too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in your `updateItem()` method you have to check if the item is empty like this:

```
static class ColoredCell extends ListCell<Float>{
    @Override
    public void updateItem(Float number, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(number, empty);

        if(number == null || empty) {
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {

            setText(number.toString()); // This line is very important!

            if (number < 6.0f){
                this.setTextFill(Color.RED);
            } else {
                this.setTextFill(Color.GREEN);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:
You have to set the text of the cell manually because you are redefining how the cell will be rendered so you have to add all the graphical components and values needed (for exemple if you want to add an icon for each mark, due to the fact that you don't use the default cell anymore, you have to call in the ColoredCell class the `setGraphic()` method.

Comment: checking if the number was null worked, but still can't get text colored

Comment: Mmm... at this point I don't know anymore what could cause the problem, I'll do some tests and see if I find a way to make that work.

Comment: @UmbertoPalazzini I made a few tests and happened that the text of the cell just disappeared. The problem is that you have not added any text to the cell, in order to do this you need to call the `setText()` method of the ListCell.